# Is there a way to modify the context menu in vscode？

Tags: visual-studio-code, contextmenu

The increase in extensions makes the context menu (right-click menu) longer and longer, and it's hard to quickly find the function I need in it.

I'd like to remove some of these items added by extensions to make vscode more concise.